# Updated attribute of a class name keeps changing to its original value

Tags: html, vba, web

A portion of my code below was able to change the attribute of a checkbox class name in a website. The code ran just fine resulting a check-mark displayed as expected but after I updated the page, that check-mark was just gone and the checkbox returned unchecked. My goal here is to tick that check box and be able to save that change.

'Code to update checkbox class name:

```
Set elements = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("i")(2)
if elements.classname = "fa fa-square-o no" then
   elements.classname = "fa fa-check-square yes"
end if
```

Below is the inspected html elements:

*Before changing class name

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" aria-readonly="true" aria-required="true" class="wj-cell dt-boolean wj-align-center" style="left: 538px; top: 116px; width: 39px; height: 29px;"><i class="fa fa-square-o no"></i></div>
<i class="fa fa-square-o no"></i>
```

*After changing class name

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" aria-readonly="true" aria-required="true" class="wj-cell dt-boolean wj-align-center" style="left: 538px; top: 116px; width: 39px; height: 29px;"><i class="fa fa-square-o no"></i></div>
<i class="fa fa-check-square yes"></i>
```

*After manually un-checked the box and right clicked on the box to inspect elements, this new html code popped up

```
<div class="axm-grid-active-editor" style="display: block; top: 225px; left: 568px; width: 38px; height: 29px;"> <div class="df__control no-border is_modified " aria-label=""><div class="df__control--boolean"><span class="modified-flag"></span>  <label class="switch switch-green"><input type="checkbox" class="switch-input"> <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span></label></div></div></div>
```

*HTML code after manually clicked on the checkbox

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" aria-readonly="true" aria-required="true" class="wj-cell dt-boolean wj-align-center axm-current-cell" style="left: 538px; top: 174px; width: 39px; height: 29px;"><i class="fa fa-check-square yes"></i><span class="k-dirty "></span></div>
```

I'm still learning to use VBA to control website. Hopefully these information provides y'all enough information to give me some guidelines. If not, please let me know, I'll see if I can give out anything else.

Thanks y'all.

Comment: Is this a public url that can be shared?

Comment: @QHarr: sorry, this is a private url but if you need any other html codes, let me know if i can find them. Thanks. (P/S:It looks like I'm not able to adjust what's inside the checkbox field.)

Comment: what do you mean by update the page? Unless you control the page all changes will be lost on page refresh. Normally automating a tickbox is part of a selection process prior to getting a new (different) page or downloading something.

Comment: @QHarr: the page has an update button to save all changes made in text boxes. When i click that update button or click on another other text boxes, all changes made in text boxes will be gone. A manual process would be clicking on a box before entering a value or clicking on the check box to mark it. Looks like I need to somehow control the mouse to click on the text box first then apply the code because once i left click a text box, a new html class will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of research, I was able to do what i needed to by using Selenium and Sendkey method.